# div not sticking to left side of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way that the first div which contains YMDW buttons be fixed on the left side and not move when the screen is enlarged?
And also add some space between YMDW div and input box div.
I'm very new to bootstrap and it already taken me days on this problem.
thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-1 col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 form-inline">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd pull-right float-right" value="Y" data-viewid="view_yearly">
        <font class="pull-right float-right">&nbsp;</font>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd pull-right float-right" value="M" data-viewid="view_monthly">
        <font class="pull-right float-right">&nbsp;</font>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-blue900_rsd pull-right float-right" value="W" data-viewid="view_weekly">
        <font class="pull-right float-right">&nbsp;</font>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd pull-right float-right" value="D" data-viewid="view_dayly">
        <font class="pull-right float-right">&nbsp;</font>
     </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-inline">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tx_front_dt" style="text-align:center;width:150px;font-weight:bold;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs form-inline ">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-1 clearfix">
     <input type="button" id="btn_view_inc_page" class="btn btn-blue900_rsd " value="LOGOUT" data-unit-type="upper" data-num="1"><font>&nbsp;</font>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the CSS for your `div` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the classes 'pull-right' and 'float-right' from the buttons, the div will get stuck to the left of the screen.

```
<div class="col-1 col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 form-inline">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd" value="Y" data-viewid="view_yearly">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd" value="M" data-viewid="view_monthly">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-blue900_rsd" value="W" data-viewid="view_weekly">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-grey300_rsd" value="D" data-viewid="view_dayly">
</div>
```